# PIL running slowly on windows

Tags: python

I have a script that joins a bunch of 8-bit BMPs into one file, which I then process with other scripts. I'm interested in speeding this procedure up. When I run on linux, it takes about 10 seconds per 100 images. When I run on windows, it takes 6 times as long.

I ran it on windows with cProfile and 325 seconds out of a total run time of 356 seconds (1000 images) was spent on {method 'encode' of 'ImagingEncoder' objects}. It's interesting because for 1000 images it runs this command 63000 times.

Do you have any ideas on how I can speed the code up, both in linux, but especially on windows. The part of the code that is reading the files is as follows, with f being the output file:

```
import PIL.Image as p
from clint.textui import progress

for i in progress.bar(xrange(0,len(file_list))):
    deets = p.open(file_list[i])
    if deets.mode != 'L':
        deets = deets.convert(mode='L')            
    f.write(deets.tostring())
```

Comment: are the machines similar in terms of specs?

Comment: Yes. If anything windows machine should be faster.